# Как сделать input[type="range"] кроссбраузерным (обрезается ползунок по краям в edge)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, input

Есть ползунок `range`, отображение которого хочу сделать кроссбраузерным, но не получается это сделать в браузере `edge`. 
Ползунок почему-то обрезается сверху и снизу, а [здесь](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/FtnAa) нет.

[image: ползунок]

[фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/89q16nrb/20/) и Код:

```css
.calculator-add-credit {
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.calculator-add-credit__text {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: none;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7px;
  left: 0;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FEEC1C;
  border: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FEEC1C;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 7px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #FEEC1C;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #FEEC1C;
}

input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #F3F4F4;
}

input[type="range"]:focus::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #FEEC1C;
}

input[type="range"]:focus::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #F3F4F4;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator-add-credit">
  <input class="calculator-add-credit__text" type="text" value="8 450 000">
  <input type="range" name="calculator-add-credit__range-1" class="calculator-add-credit__range" min="1000000" max="10000000" step="50000">
</div>
<div class="calculator-add-credit">
  <input class="calculator-add-credit__text" type="text" value="8 450 000">
  <input type="range" name="calculator-add-credit__range-2" class="calculator-add-credit__range" min="1000000" max="10000000" step="50000">
</div>
```

Comment: тут смотрели? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389224/how-to-style-html5-range-input-to-have-different-color-before-and-after-slider

Comment: @Oleksandr спасибо! вот только фон не удается сделать прозрачным, только белый

Comment: rgba 4 параметр не срабатывает?

Comment: @Oleksandr ну я вот так сделал
http://jsfiddle.net/JnrvG/4031/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JnrvG/4041/
а почему не чистым css, как в примере ниже?

Comment: @Oleksandr похоже до него не добрался